# Combining indiscernible sequences

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, model-theory

Fix some structure $M$ and $C\subseteq M$. Suppose $(a_i)_{i<\omega}\subset M$ and $(b_i)_{i<\omega}\subset M$ are $C$-indiscernible sequences. Can we conclude that $(a_ib_i)_{i\leq \omega}$ is $C$-indiscernible sequence as well?

Comment: What have you tried? Maybe start here: every element of an indiscernible sequence has the same type. Can you prove or find a counterexample to the proposition that $\mathrm{tp}(a_0b_0/C) = \mathrm{tp}(a_1b_1/C)$?

Comment: @AlexKruckman I could not find a counterexample!

Comment: What if $a_0=b_0$?

Comment: @AlexKruckman I got it. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. If you have a solution, you can write an answer to your own question and accept it, so the question is marked as answered - and to help future users with the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I'm going to answer my question based on Alex Kruckman's hint in the comments.

The answer is NO. Here is a counterexample!

[image]

In this picture $(a_i)_{i<\omega}$ and $(b_i)_{i<\omega}$ are indiscernible sequences but  $\text{tp}(a_0b_0)=\text{tp}(a_0)\neq \text{tp}(a_1b_1)$.